My Fast Report table is showing only one row. Why? How can I fix this?
In my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project, I am trying to make a report. I am trying to generate report where it have a table with 5 columns and dynamic rows. But in my case, it is always printing one row. I have 9-10 rows of data for this. But it is printing only one row.
Here is my C# file where I generate the attendance report. How can I reform it? What should I do for this only one row printing
public async Task<byte[]> GenerateAttendanceReportAsync(int sessionId, int unitId)
{
    try
    {
        // Get all required data
        var (session, unit, attendanceDetails) = await GetAttendanceDataAsync(sessionId, unitId);

        // Create DataSet for proper data binding
        var ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt = CreateDataTable(attendanceDetails, unit.UnitName);
        dt.TableName = "tabledata"; // Match the table name in template
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        // Generate report
        using var report = new Report();
        string templatePath = GetTemplatePath();

        await using (var fileStream = new FileStream(templatePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            report.Load(fileStream);
        }

        // Register data and parameters
        RegisterDataAndParameters(report, ds, session.SessionName, unit.UnitName);

        // Generate PDF
        return await GeneratePdfAsync(report);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var message = GetDetailedErrorMessage(ex);
        throw new ReportGenerationException(message, ex);
    }
}

And my XLM file is
<TableDataSource Name="tabledata" DataType="System.Int32" Enabled="true">
  <Column Name="SerialNo" DataType="System.Int32"/>
  <Column Name="RollNumber" DataType="System.Int32"/>
  <Column Name="ApplicantName" DataType="System.String"/>
  <Column Name="DistrictName" DataType="System.String"/>
  <Column Name="Picture" DataType="System.Byte[]"/>
  <Column Name="Status" DataType="System.String"/>
</TableDataSource>

<DataBand Name="Data1" Top="89.05" Width="718.2" Height="103.95" DataSource="tabledata">
  <TableObject Name="Table1" Left="47.25" Width="623.7" Height="103.95">
    <TableColumn Name="Column1" Width="47.25"/>
    <TableColumn Name="Column2" Width="141.75"/>
    <TableColumn Name="Column3" Width="160.65"/>
    <TableColumn Name="Column4" Width="122.85"/>
    <TableColumn Name="Column5" Width="94.5"/>
    <TableColumn Name="Column6" Width="56.7"/>
    <TableRow Name="HeaderRow" Height="56.7">
      <TableCell Name="HeaderCell1" Border.Lines="All" Text="Sl" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 11.25pt, style=Bold"/>
      <TableCell Name="HeaderCell2" Border.Lines="All" Text="Written&#13;&#10;Examination Roll&#13;&#10;No." HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 11.25pt, style=Bold"/>
      <TableCell Name="HeaderCell3" Border.Lines="All" Text="Applicant's&#13;&#10;Name" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 11.25pt, style=Bold"/>
      <TableCell Name="HeaderCell4" Border.Lines="All" Text="District&#13;&#10;Name" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 11.25pt, style=Bold"/>
      <TableCell Name="HeaderCell5" Border.Lines="All" Text="Picture" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 11.25pt, style=Bold"/>
      <TableCell Name="HeaderCell6" Border.Lines="All" Text="Status" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 11.25pt, style=Bold"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow Name="DataRow" Height="47.25">
      <TableCell Name="Cell1" Border.Lines="All" Text="[tabledata.SerialNo]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 10pt"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell2" Border.Lines="All" Text="[tabledata.RollNumber]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 10pt"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell3" Border.Lines="All" Text="[tabledata.ApplicantName]" Padding="5, 0, 5, 0" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 10pt"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell4" Border.Lines="All" Text="[tabledata.DistrictName]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 10pt"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell5" Border.Lines="All" Font="Arial, 10pt">
        <PictureObject Name="Picture1" Width="94.5" Height="47.25" DataColumn="tabledata.Picture" SizeMode="StretchImage"/>
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell Name="Cell6" Border.Lines="All" Text="[tabledata.Status]" HorzAlign="Center" VertAlign="Center" Font="Times New Roman, 10pt"/>
    </TableRow>
  </TableObject>
</DataBand>

Every time it is printing one row. I am trying to create dynamic table based on my data list.

Hi @Moonwar, could you pls share more details for what is your RegisterDataAndParameters and GeneratePdfAsync? How is your xml file used to do?
